# Spreadsheet gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using Spreadsheet gem and environment - rails 3.0.3 and ruby 1.9.2.

facing following issue -

When i have entered integer value in excel sheet,
it will be treated as ruby float value.

(for e.g -  1 in the excel is display as 1.0).

will there is any fix for this issue?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the column format with something like this:

```
    book = Spreadsheet::Workbook.new
    sheet = book.create_worksheet
    fmt_nr = Spreadsheet::Format.new :number_format => '0'
    sheet.format_column 1, fmt_nr
```

That will format the first column of the sheet as integer numbers.